# Attempting to remove a json object from an array by targeting key value

Tags: php, json

Disclaimer: I'm somewhat new to PHP. I'm trying to remove single objects from a json array, but when I attempt to delete the DOM object rectangle (each of which represents an array object), then `process.php` ends up making a copy of the array and appending it to the original array.

When I click the delete button (class `rectangle-delete`), I change the `deleteStatus` hidden input value to `delete` which I'm trying to pick up in `process.php`. This is the particular bit in `process.php` that I thought would do the trick:

```
 foreach($arr_data as $key => $value) {
        if($value->value != "delete") {
            $arr_data[] = $value;
        }
     }
```

Here is the entire `process.php`:

```
<?php

   //$myFile = "data/data.json";
   $filename = $_POST['store-template-name'];
   $myFile = "data/" . $filename;
   $arr_data = array(); // create empty array

  try
  {
       //Get form data
       $formdata = array(
          'ID'=> $_POST['ID'],
          'attributeName'=> $_POST['attributeName'],
          'deleteStatus'=> $_POST['deleteStatus'],
          'attributeType'=> $_POST['attributeType']
       );
       //Get data from existing json file
       $jsondata = file_get_contents($myFile);
       // converts json data into array
       $arr_data = json_decode($jsondata, true);
       $updateKey = null;
       foreach ($arr_data as $k => $v) {
            if ($v['ID'] == $formdata['ID']) {
                $updateKey = $k;
            }
        }
       //  delete object in json
       foreach($arr_data as $key => $value) {
          if($value->value != "delete") {
              $arr_data[] = $value;
          }
       }
        if ($updateKey === null) {
            array_push($arr_data,$formdata);
        } else {
            $arr_data[$updateKey] = $formdata;
        }

       $jsondata = json_encode($arr_data);

       //write json data into data.json file
       if(file_put_contents($myFile, $jsondata)) {
            echo 'Data successfully saved';
        }
       else
            echo "error";
   }
   catch (Exception $e) {
            echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
   }
?>
```

Comment: can you print an example of what `$arr_data` looks like (using something like `var_dump()` or `print_r`)? Also, you should only post code that is aboslutely necessary to our understanding of your problem, maybe think about removing some of the fluff in your question.

Comment: ^ It's better to use `var_export();` :)

Comment: Really do you get `delete Id` or `update id`?  Or both are availiable simultaneously?

Comment: @WilliamPerron Sure, $arr_data looks like `[{"ID":"12","attributeName":"PatientName","valueX":"413","valueY":"175.71875","valueHeight":"28","valueWidth":"207","valueURL":"www.test.com","attributeType":"missing-element", {"deleteStatus":"no_delete"}}, {"ID":"13","attributeName":"PatientName","valueX":"433","valueY":"155.71243","valueHeight":"44","valueWidth":"254","valueURL":"www.test.com","attributeType":"missing-element"}, {"deleteStatus":"delete"}]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you are trying to filter your `$arr_data` array to remove the entities when the value is "delete", Am I right? If yes, you could try this.

```
foreach($arr_data as $key => $value) {
   if($value->value != "delete") {
     $arr_data[] = $value;
   }else{
      unset($arr_data[$key]);
   }
}
```

or this

```
$arr_data = array_filter($arr_data, function($value){
     return $value->value != "delete";
});
```

Comment: Anderson, when I attempt the first block of code you suggested (in place of my own at the same spot), it doubles the size of the array by creating duplicates of each ID. Do you know why that is?

Comment: And yes, you are correct that I'm trying to remove the objects whose value for the key `deleteStatus` is `delete`.

Comment: In your example you are looking for wrong key `$value->value == "delete"` in this case, you should be look for `$value->deleteStatus == "delete"`

Comment: I was looking your json and i think the structure it is wrong. Because you are looking for a key "deleteStatus" that not exists in all objects and in some objects the key exists, but inside an another object, because this, you can`t found the value when your call `$value->deleteStatus == "delete"`. You must define a standard for your json structure for prevent problems like this.

Comment: take a look here: https://gist.github.com/andersao/e8aef769fe30bd314c0f25c91ad4748b

Comment: Anderson, I'm not sure I see the problem with the gist. I'm just wanting to eliminate the whole second object since the key `deleteStatus` has the value `delete`. Am I thinking about this wrong?